# why does my java program not iterate?

Tags: java, loops, logic, iteration

This is supposed to check if an int occurs at a specific index in an array or at any other index over that. However, my for loop doesn't loop

```
public static boolean searchIterative(int[] list, int f, int x){
    for (; f<list.length;f++){
        return list[f]==x;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `return` statement does?

Comment: Because you didn't study enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return immediately after entering your loop. `return` exits the loop (and the function.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether or not the value is true, the first time you enter the loop you return a true or false - you return the conditional statement list[f]==x;

You want to iterate through until you find it, and then return true, or return false if you never find it. If you need to find if it's in multiple places you need to count each time you find it within the method, and then return that.